# Stream does not support reading when calling SendEmailAsync

Tags: c#, mailmessage, system.net.mail

I'm trying to attach a file that's provided in a byte array as an attachment in an email but I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception: Failure sending mail.
InnerException: Stream does not support reading.
```

But that's it. Not much to go with!

I'm attaching the byte array file as follows:

```
using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
{
    message.Subject = subject;
    ....
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(attachment.Data))
    {
        message.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, attachment.Name));
    }
}
```

Note that the `attachment` variable is our own class which just provides additional information about the file including `.Data` which contains the byte array representing the file.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: @IanKemp Thanks for that. It is now working. Kind of weird having a variable at the class level for something like that but it is being disposed, so no major concern. Main thing is that it is working. Thanks again!

Comment: I'll go ahead and delete the question I guess

Comment: No need to delete - this question still has value as a signpost to the other question that has an answer to this problem. From https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates "The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place."

Comment: @IanKemp, ok fair. I'll leave it then :). Thanks

Comment: I came here from Google and followed the link to fix my issue, thank you.